# Remove all exclamation marks from the end of sentence

Tags: regex, string

I need a few lines of code to remove all exclamation marks ("!") starting from the end of the sentence. The code should achieve the following:

```
"Hi!" --> "Hi"
"Hi!!!" --> "Hi"
"!Hi") --> "!Hi"
"Hi! Hi!") --> "Hi! Hi"
```

I've tried using RegEx (negative lookahead), however, to no success:

```
/(?!^)!/g
```

A short explanation of the solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lookahead. Just match the exclamation points at the end and replace them with an empty string. In PHP this is:

```
$string = preg_replace('/!+$/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `$` anchor, which marks the end of a string:

```
/!+$/gm
```

The `m` flag is there in case you have a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you the solution which i have implemented in the javascript. I don't know which language you are using but anyways logic remains the same.

```
var text = "!Hi! Hi!!";
var i=text.length - 1;
while(text[i] == "!"){
   i--;
}
finalText = text.substring(0,i+1);
console.log(finalText);

Output: !Hi! Hi
```

You can use same logic to implement in the programming language you are using. If you want to use Regex then the solution mentioned by @Barmar above will work perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

```
def remove(s):
    return s[:-1] if s.endswith('!') else s
```

It should be good

Comment: This only removes the last ! in the string, it does not consider if there are multiple !! at the end of the string.